# collectionView cellForItemAt not being called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a `UITableView` where each prototype cell has a `UICollectionView` in it. This collection view is supposed to be a grid of images. I'm very new to Swift, and have googled for hours (and read plenty of StackOverflow articles), and cannot seem to find the correct answer to this question.

How come collectionView cellForItemAt is not being called?

I see that my collectionView `numberOfItemsInSection` method, and collectionView `sizeForItemAt` methods get called. I've made sure to assign my `TableViewCell` as the delegate and dataSource of the collectionView. I did this both in the Interface Builder with outlets, and again in my custom TableViewCell's `awakeFromNib` method with

```
cardImagesCollection.delegate = self
cardImagesCollection.dataSource = self
```

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get this to call it. I made sure that I had good constraints set up because that burned me once on the tableViewCells.

For the life of me, I cannot get it to load up the collectionView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Specifically, I'm using Xcode 9.4.1 and Swift 4.1.

Thanks

## Edit - Adding sample code

### HomeViewController: UIViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LatestCardCell", for: indexPath) as! LatestCardsTableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.card = cards[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

### LatestCardsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell

```
@IBOutlet weak var cardImagesCollection: UICollectionView!

var card: Card! {
    didSet {
        titleLabel.attributedText = FontUtil.attributedCardTitleText(string: card.title)
        descriptionLabel.attributedText = FontUtil.attributedCardDescriptionText(string: card.description)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("count")
    return card.imageUrls.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("here")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LatestCardsImage", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! LatestCardImageCell

    //let url = card.imageUrls[indexPath.row]
    //cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "test")

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
}
```

### LatestCardImageCell: UICollectionViewCell

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

## Edit 2: Summary of suggestions I've tried

People have suggested setting the dataSource and delegate for the CollectionView inside the `cellForRowAt` call where I build the CollectionView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LatestCardCell", for: indexPath) as! LatestCardsTableViewCell

    cell.cardImagesCollection.delegate = cell
    cell.cardImagesCollection.dataSource = cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.card = cards[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

This did not change anything. They also suggested adding the following inside of that cellForRowAt call right after setting cell.card:

```
cell.cardImagesCollection.reloadData()
```

This also did not change anything.

I've put breakpoints and logging in my TableViewCell's custom class and I can see that `numberOfItemsInSection` gets calls once per TableViewCell, and it returns the correct number (this number varies between TableViewCell). I then also see `sizeForItemAt` get called the exact amount of times that `numberOfItemsInSection` returns. I do not, however, see the `cellForItemAt` method get called ever.

Here's the logging:

```
numberOfItemsInSection: 6
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 0
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 1
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 2
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 3
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 4
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 5
numberOfItemsInSection: 2
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 0
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 1
numberOfItemsInSection: 4
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 0
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 1
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 2
sizeForItemAt: Section 0 Row 3
```

Some have suggested making sure to define `cellForItemAt` by using autocomplete as opposed to copying and pasting, which is how I did it in the first place. I also have my custom TableViewCell set up with the following protocols `UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and it does not complain about a lack of `cellForItemAt` method. I currently have the delegate and dataSource set in the InterfaceBuilder and that is what is giving me the method calls I'm seeing.

I've tried calling `reloadData()` on the collectionView in multiple places (the second I set the `cell.card` in my `cellForRowAt`, in my `didSet` call, and even the `awakeFromNib` method in the custom TableViewCell. Nothing works.

Other aspects of the TableCell render, but not this image collection. I've hardcoded a size for the CollectionView cells in the InterfaceBuilder, and even overrode sizeForItemAt to always return `CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)`, just to be sure that the issue isn't having a cell that's too small to be visible. The tableView cell is set to auto height with `latestCardsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, and I've added long text to my labels to ensure that they do grow in size with the text automatically.

Does anyone have any other ideas? Are there things I can screenshot from the InterfaceBuilder, or some Swift code I can write to force some AutoLayout stuff? I'm open to anything.

## Edit 3: A glimmer of hope

I've found that if I give my UITableViewCell an explicit large height, the UICollectionView does show up and does call `cellForItemAt`. So, how do I set my constraints so that the UICollectionView forces the UITableViewCell larger, given that I've got `rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` set on my TableView?

[image: Collection View Constriants]

Comment: can check your sample code ?

Comment: Without seeing any code how we can understand your problem, so many ways are there to get this type of problem, can you show your code

Comment: Probably the function is wrong if you do copy paste, try to write it yourself and use auto complete

Comment: Your code will give better understanding of your issue.

Comment: Make sure the height of UITableViewCell is not zero(Means UICollectionView is displayed).

Comment: Sorry guys. I just updated the post. The UITableViewCell is not zero. They auto-size the height by setting rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension. I can see my two labels in it, it just doesn't render the collection view below.

Comment: Is your `numberOfItemsInSection` returns > 0?

Comment: Make sure number of item  collection-view datasource is not Zero.

Comment: Reload both tableview&collectionview

Comment: numberOfItemsInSection is definitely greater than 0. I've even hardcoded it to 10 to see if I could get something to show. Logging shows that the method gets called and returns the correct number. How do I reload the tableView and collectionView? And when should I do that?

Comment: Use `collectionView.reloadData()` in `cellForRowAt ` of TableView.

Comment: `cell.cardImagesCollection.reloadData()` also does not make the collection show. I do see `numberOfItemsInSection` and `sizeForItemAt` getting called correctly, but there are no `cellForItemAt` calls happening.

Comment: how do you know it is not being called?

Comment: I've put a print statement in the method and see nothing in my console. I put a print statement in it. `numberOfItemsInSection` and `sizeForItemAt` get called the correct amount of times, but `cellForItemAt` does not print anything and does not display, so I can only assume it's not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do following,
Write a method in your LatestCardsTableViewCell class,

```
func configureCell() {
      cardImagesCollection.reloadData()
}
```

and call this method, in HomeViewController's cellForRowAtIndexPath like following,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LatestCardCell", for: indexPath) as! LatestCardsTableViewCell

cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
cell.card = cards[indexPath.row]
cell. configureCell()
return cell
}
```

Comment: I did try that and it doesn't work either. I actually even tried putting `cardImagesCollection.reloadData()` in my `didSet` for the card, since that's what the images CollectionView feeds off of.

Comment: Have you checked adding breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Are you sure that method is not getting calleD?

Comment: Yes. I've also put a print statement in the method and see nothing in my console. I put print statements in and numberOfItemsInSection and sizeForItemAt get called the correct amount of times, but cellForItemAt does not print anything and does not display and does not hit the breakpoint, so I'm pretty confident that it's not being called.

Comment: Can you try removing all the constraints for collectionView and just fix constraint warning by selecting 'add missing constraints'?

Comment: Hmm, forcing a large height to the table view cell DOES make the content show in the collection view. So, now the question is, how do I set the constraints to have the collection view force the table view cell open?

Comment: I think what you can do is, set one IBOutlet for your collection view height,
@IBOutlet var height: NSLayoutConstraint
Calculate your collection view's height based on number of cells and assign calculated height to above mentioned outlet.
Once you do it properly. tableView should automatically adjust it's cell height as you have set,
rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: I was able to do that and it's working great! Thanks a lot!